# How to use variables in routes in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-routing

I'm trying to build a application in `laravel 5.3` in which I get the variable from request method and then trying to pass that variable in a redirect to the routes. I want to use this variable in my view so that I can be able to display the value of variable. I'm currently doing this:

In my controller I'm getting the request like this:

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $data = request->only('xyz','abc');
    // Do some coding
    .
    .
    $member['xyz'] = $data['xyz'];
    $member['abc'] = $data['abc'];
    return redirect('member/memberinfo')->with('member' => $member);
}
```

Now I've following in my routes:

```
Route::get('/member/memberinfo', 'MemberController@memberinfo')->with('member', $member);
```

Now in `MemberController` I want to use `$member` variable and display this into my view:

```
public function memberinfo()
{
  return view('member.memberinfo', ['member' => $member]);
}
```

But I'm getting an error in the routes files

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::with()

Help me out, how can I achieve this.

Comment: Just replace `=>` with `,` at `with('member' => $member);`. Hope this helps and solve your issue!!

Comment: Just read that documentation,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `redirect()->with()`, you're saving data to the session. So to get data from the session in controller or even view you can use `session()` helper:

```
$member = session('member'); // In controller.

{{ session('member')['xyz'] }} // In view.
```

Alternatively, you could pass variables as string parameters.

Redirect:

```
return redirect('member/memberinfo/xyz/abc')
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/member/memberinfo/{xyz}/{abc}', 'MemberController@memberinfo');
```

Controller:

```
public function memberinfo($xyz, $abc)
{
    return view('member.memberinfo', compact('xyz', 'abc'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for constantly answering my questions. It helped me lot in learning laravel!

Comment: For anyone else viewing this, keep in mind that you can use Route Model Binding: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

route:

```
Route::get('/member/memberinfo', 'MemberController@memberinfo')
```

and the redirect:

```
return redirect('member/memberinfo')->with('member', $member);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `=>` with `,`

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $data = request->only('xyz','abc');
    // Do some coding
    .
    .
    $member['xyz'] = $data['xyz'];
    $member['abc'] = $data['abc'];
    return redirect('member/memberinfo')->with('member', $member); // => needs to be replaced with ,
}
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

```
return redirect('member/memberinfo')->with('member' => $member);
```

to

```
return redirect('member/memberinfo')->with('member', $member);
```

......