# Pass two variable to method in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-6.2

i want to find post by slug also in url ..
but the comments must be found by post_id

Controller

```
public function post($slug,$id)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    $comments = Comment::where('post_id',$id)->get();
    return view('content.post',compact('post','comments'));
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('post/{slug}', 'PagesController@post')->name('post.show');
```

Comment: is this `$id` not equal to `$post` id?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use variables in routes in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466153/how-to-use-variables-in-routes-in-laravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::get('post/{slug}', 'PagesController@post')->name('post.show');
```

```
public function post($slug)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    $comments = Comment::where('post_id',$post->id)->get();
    return view('content.post',compact('post','comments'));
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't handle errors. If a Post entity isn't found by the provided slug, you will get a notice and a method call error, that isn't handled.

Comment: Just change `$post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first() or abort(404);` to handle error (not found)

Comment: @WahyuKristianto Or use proper model binding instead, which would handle this out of the box without additional code to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Get `post_id` from the `$post` itself.

```
public function post($slug){
    $post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    $comments = Comment::where('post_id',$post->id)->get();
    ...
}
```

Comment: @HamadEssa You don't need to show $id in your URL. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

in web.php:

```
Route::get('post/{slug}', 'PagesController@post')->name('post.show');
```

in controller:

```
public function post($slug)
{
    $post = Post::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    $comments = Comment::where('post_id',$post->id)->get(); //use founded_post_id to find it's comments
    return view('content.post',compact('post','comments'));
}
```

Comment: i edited my answer, you can reach your `$post` by `slug` and then reach to it's comments by using `$post->id` like my answer, in this way in url your id won't show

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#route-model-binding) to ensure that routes will find your model based on the provided key.

Your `Post` model will require that you add the following method:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Then, in your routes, you can just refer the model directly, and binding will happen automatically:

```
public function post(App\Post $post)
{
    $comments = Comment::where('post_id',$post->id)->get();
    return view('content.post',compact('post','comments'));
}
```

This enables you to to use the following route:

```
Route::get('post/{post}', 'PagesController@post')->name('post.show');
```

Now, additionally, to ease up your reference of the comments, add them as relations to your `Post` model:

```
public function comments() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

and your `Comment` model:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

This will allow you to shorten your controller method even more:

```
public function post(App\Post $post)
{
    return view('content.post',compact('post'));
}
```

and in your Blade view do the following instead:

```
@foreach($post->comments as $comment)
From: {{ $comment->name }} blah blha
@endforeach
```